# Using python request library to get HTTP Error String

Tags: python, http, httprequest

I've been asked to swap over from `urllib2` to the `requests` library because the library is simpler to use and doesn't cause exceptions.

I can get the HTTP error code with `response.status_code` but I don't see a way to get the error message for that code.  Normally, I wouldn't care, but I'm testing an API and the string is just as important.

Does anybody know of a simple way to get that string?  I'm expecting 2 pieces something like:

```
'400':'Bad Request'
```

Comment: Well not very elegant but I wrote this to make it easier to deal with:
`def GetHTTPErrorStr( self, error ):
  errStr = ''

  try:
   errStr = requests.status_codes._codes[error][0]
  except:
   errStr = 'Unknown HTTP Error in GetHTTPErrorStr'
 
  return errStr
`

Comment: I was trying to add code chunks but it isn't working 
` def GetHTTPErrorStr( self, error ):
  errStr = ''

  try:
   errStr = requests.status_codes._codes[error][0]
  except:
   errStr = 'Unknown HTTP Error in GetHTTPErrorStr'
 
  return errStr`

Comment: Actually... this unfortunately isn't a good enough answer.  Some of the codes being returned have unique strings being sent by the application that I am testing.  These strings cannot be looked up using this method:
  requests.status_codes._codes[error][0]
Since the string is dynamically coming from the back end server.  I was able to get this information using urllib using this method:
  except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
   try:
    error_message = err.read()